# fade out UIRefreshControl or hide it from transparent scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, refresh, uicolor, uirefreshcontrol

I'd like to hide my `UIRefreshControl` from my transparent scroll view quicker than usual with a rapid fade out so it doesn't superpose with the text. Any similar solution would be appreciated!

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
let color = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh", attributes: color)
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl

@objc func refreshData(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    updateBitcoinValueLabel()
    updateBitcoinCashValueLabel()
    updateEthereumValueLabel()
    updateLitecoinValueLabel()
    updateRippleValueLabel()
    updateWalletValueLabel()

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

[+ Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nmck.gif)

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: share your current code.. plus did you try simply hide it when the data are loaded?

Comment: update the question :)

Comment: Why not add a black background behind the content? So this problem can never happen? Also, why doesn't the content pause until the data has been loaded in?

Comment: The background looks black but actually have a texture to it. It's because the data loads superfast I believe, what would be the method to have it paused?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, 
                       withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, 
                targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
 {
     self.refreshControl.isHidden = true

 }
```

Comment: did you even try it or you are just guessing?

Comment: It's not quick enough unfortunately nor has any fading

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue replacing this:

`scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

with this:

`scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)`